# How do i convert a string value into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using selenium web driver to extract a table from a webpage by its X-path using the command

```
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ccs_VC_caps_dataTable"]').text
```

This gives me

```
FC Ship Method Sort Code Destination Warehouse Ship Option Group Name Effective Start Date Effective End Date Day of the week Start Time End Time(exclusive) Time Zone Constraint Type Unit of Measurement Soft Cap Hard Cap MinTarget Max Penalty % Time
Las2 K_PARCEL_24 2019-07-04 2019-07-04 All Europe/London Cubic Volume Cap CUBIC_METER 61 67
Las2 K_PARCEL_24 2019-07-04 2019-07-04 All Europe/London Package Count Cap 1402 1450
Las2 K_PARCEL_48_LL 2019-07-04 2019-07-04 All Europe/London Cubic Volume Cap CUBIC_METER 16 10
Las2 K_PARCEL_48_LL 2019-07-04 2019-07-04 All Europe/London Package Count Cap 125 77
```

which is of string type

I want to convert this to a pandas data frame.
Do I have to use beautfifulsoup or is there any workaround where I can extract the table by its X-path and convert it into a pandas data frame?

Comment: I'm not used to pandas but I think that you could use `pd.read_table(your_xpath_str, sep=" ")`. See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html)

Answer (score 0):

create DataFrame using string Split method 
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in table.split('\n')])

Comment: It gives me "ValueError: empty separator"

Comment: use space x.split('space')

Comment: It worked. But the first line has headers with spaces in between which is expanding the size of the dataframe and taking none values.
Is there a way I can implement this from the second line?

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can skip headers..

`pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for i, x in enumerate(table.split('\n')) if i != 0])`

Comment: This might be a different question altogether, but is there any way to shift the rows to left when there is a keyword CUBIC_METER
I want that occurrence of CUBIC_METER to be deleted and the rows be shifted left